# Long ListView optimization and usability

Tags: android

I have a long list to display in a listview. Let's say 200 items. This is a long list, but i can't reduce it. Now my list is slow and is not convenient for the user.

I need something like a paging system: at the beginning I load 25 items. When the user reach the end I show a button, or something like it, to load other 25 items. An Iphone style solution.

Is there a better way? Or what is the best solution?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An [autogrow](http://www.androidjunkies.com/index.php/2009/10/21/tutorial-autogrowing-listview/) list will be the suitable UI design pattern.